# get the last column in every file using open

Tags: python, pandas, csv

how can i get the last column of an open file. I mean, it isn't the problem to do this with a panda dataframen. 
I using for this problem the open methode to get only a few needed information out of different txt files. The mean problem is, that the result_metar is in different columns and isn't fixed on column 21.

```
for xx in range(len(fns_land)):
   with open(fns_land[xx]) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            result_station.append(line.split(',')[0])
            result_date.append(line.split(',')[1])
            result_metar.append(line.split(',')[21])
```

is there a way to using iloc for example and change the fixed value 21?

The answer i found only show pandas solutions.

Thanks a lot.

Best

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a sample file

Comment: The complet file is to big. This is way i use a sequentiell reading solution.But i can show you how it looks like.

Comment: Just a sample...1 or 2 line..so that folks can understand what is result_metar, result_date..and so on

Comment: DAOV,2015-01-01 00:00,33.80,30.20,86.49,0.00,0.00,0.00,30.39,M,6.21,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,DAOV 010000Z 00000KT CAVOK 01/M01 Q1029

Comment: I use the station (column0], the date (column 1) and last but not least the last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can return the last column of each open file regardless of the size of your file:

```
for xx in range(len(fns_land)):
    with open(path) as infile:
         lines = infile.readlines()
         for line in lines:
             result_station.append(line.split(',')[0])
             result_date.append(line.split(',')[1])
             result_metar.append(line.split(',')[-1])
```

Comment: I didn't get any values back. With [21] i get: DAOV 010000Z 00000KT...... with your solution the list is blank.

Comment: The method `readlines()` reads until EOF using readline() and returns a list containing the lines. In this method you have all the lines in your file once as a list. So you can apply split(',') on it.

Comment: Ah now i understand it.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask.... Now i only get on line of the file. If i switch back to 21 it runs and i get a list... if i use youre line only one line is append... Can you help me a second time?

Comment: You mean with my code you just have only last line, but with your code you have all lines plus the last line(which is 21), right?

Comment: Yes. But I think if i have a loop over a append i get a list of it.

Comment: I edited the answer, check if you have still the same problem.

Comment: Hi Ssein... same problem. if there is the fix number it runs... with variable end column every append is empty in this loop

Comment: I think there are some space in the contents of your file(with variable end column). To make sure, could you `print lines` and check what is inside of each list element(column). If you see some empty element inside you should remove it like `lines = [x.strip(' ') for x in infile.readlines()]`, otherwise replace `result_metar.append(line.strip().split(',')[-1])`. If not, can you provide a sample  **with variable end column*?

Comment: With your edit it is now running, but your code have one big disadvantage. You read the compete file in the memory. The first resolution was line by line, also my version. Know I get in some cases Kills. -.-

Comment: Yes your're right and I am fully aware of that. Because it is  to often the fastest way to read a variable amount of data. However, the docs for `readlines()` indicate there is an optional sizehint. Use readlines(1), which hints one line, but in fact reads in about 4k or 8k worth of lines IIRC. This takes advantage of the OS buffering and reduces the number of calls somewhat without using an excessive amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to point out that you're calling the line.split() multiple times, which is in-optimal. Instead you could split the line once by assigning the split result list to variable. Then it's just a matter of picking the items from the list.

But... In reality I'd go with this:

```
for filename in fns_land:
    with open(filename) as infile:
       last_line = infile.readlines()[-1]
       last_column = last_line.split(',')[-1]
       result_metar.append(last_column)

       """ 
       # alternatively 3 lines above could be just be one command, such as
       result_metar.append( (infile.readlines()[-1]).split(',')[-1] )
       """
```

Comment: In your case i get a empty result_metar[] but i don't now way :D